# Creating a Default Value for a Primary Key Cell in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, automation

Is there a way to create a data extension that has a primary key with a blank value, and when a new row is added, to autopopulate that primary key field with a unique number in a sequence? E.g. Rows Zip, City , State, Primary Key, 74133 Tulsa Oklahoma 1234, 90210 Beverly Hills CA 12345?

Comment: How the rows will be filled? With an SQL automation? And this PK needs to be numeric?

Comment: I think you could use something like this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272521/can-i-update-data-extension-with-auto-generated-random-value

Comment: Out of the box, there isn't a feature that provides this. However, you could 1) pre-populate your target DE with sequenced numeric values (perhaps create an automation that adds several daily), 2) insert a function to get a count of the rows in the DE before performing an Upsert(), then add 1, and use that value as the SK. Keep in mind, all DEs have a hidden column _CustomObjectKey that is a numeric value that grows sequentially (thing is, if you update the DE, the numbers reset). https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105901/how-to-create-an-auto-increment-field-in-data-extension

Comment: @Leto Primary Key doesn't have to be numeric, just an example.